# Keyword not supported 'metadata', windows application with EF

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-6

I have created an installer for windows application with Entity Framework 6, and it got installed and working fine on a test machine, but on the client-side, after installation it always giving error "keyword not supported 'metadata'". I have done a bit research and tried several options in app.config connectionsting, removed all metadata tag keep only connection string with System.Data.Entityclient, but it started giving error again "keyword not supported 'data source'". Can anyone please guide?

Comment: any comments plz